# Tokenization based on regex and retain the match pattern

Tags: python, regex, bash

I want to split a file using a regex pattern such that the file gets tokenized on following three delimiters.

1. /
2. &
3. ?

The condition is that I want to retain the delimiter in the final output.

e.g.

**Input File:**

```
/wp-admin/wellsfargo/index.html/
/e1452e05fde1b15e51fc5a30065a5689?login=_&.verify?service=_&data:text/html;charset=_
/hZfAh
```

**Expected Output:**

```
/wp-admin
/wellsfargo
/index.html
/e1452e05fde1b15e51fc5a30065a5689
?login=_
&.verify
?service=_
&data:text
/html;charset=_
/hZfAh
```

How to do this using either Python or Bash?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: You need to include your current attempt(s) and describe what's going wrong. Users here object to just being given a brief to fulfil, for hopefully obvious reasons

Comment: @Clive I am new to Stack OF and was wondering why I got downvoted. Thank you so much for pinpointing my mistake. I'll take care of this thing from now onwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input is stored in variable `s`, y ou can use `re.findall` with the following regex pattern:

```
import re
print('\n'.join(re.findall(r'[/&?][^/&?\n]+', s)))
```

This outputs:

```
/wp-admin
/wellsfargo
/index.html
/e1452e05fde1b15e51fc5a30065a5689
?login=_
&.verify
?service=_
&data:text
/html;charset=_
/hZfAh
```